# QT5 Mac os and hibernate

Tags: macos, hibernate, networking, qt5

i have an app on mac what is polling in a minute interval data from my server. When the mac is not used for longer time he goes to hibernate mode. After waking him up, everything works fine, except the polling, this is broken and will only work again after i restart my app. Connections to other sources over the network work fin, only the connection to my server is broken.
It looks like the mac waits still for the response of the last requests he did before he went to hibernate, but this will never come.

is there a way to detect the hibernate mode and reset somehow the network requests in this cases

with regards 
Georg

Comment: How about a simple timeout? If you do this polling once every minute, and you don't get a response within a minute (when the next polling should happen) then you could simply consider the connection stale and attempt to reconnect. Should work for the hibernation issue as well as in the general case when the peer becomes unresponsive.

Comment: How would you implement here a timeout? not sure if its a good idea to use here a QTimer, while there are a lot of requests going out to my server

Comment: The simplest way might be to just check if you have received a reply when you next want to send a polling request. If no reply have been received since last poll, you have a timeout.

Comment: that's a good idea, but in this case, i normally have already the problem that the next request will fail because of the network problem after hibernate, do you have any suggests how i can reset in this case the network, so its starting to connect again to my server?